# Simple sample Velocity examples

Tags: java, oop, velocity, web-frameworks

Please recommend open source web applications that use velocity for html generation, that would be good examples to learn from.

Want to try using velocity for my next web app but want to learn from more experienced people first (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Roller does.  Also the example applications that come with the VelocityTools project.  Liferay.  And plenty of frameworks include Velocity support and examples.  Apache Click is one of the better of those.